# Deleting multiple files in terminal

Tags: unix

I am using Python to develop on a particular project. But one thing's disturbing is the `.pyc` files that crop up.

```
% find `pwd` | grep '.pyc'
```

This returns a list of files in my current directory. How can I delete them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

Comment: Oh isn't that ingenious. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

You could also pipe the output from your `find` command to the `xargs` command.

```
% find . -name '*.pyc' | xargs rm -f
```